# How to validate phone numer in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, validation, phone-number

How to validating Phone numbers using Regx method.
The problem is I want to Validate different formats of Phone numbers.I had Noted down the formats also.
1.XXXXXXXXXX
2.XXXX-XXX-XXX
3.XXXX-XX-XX-XX
4.XXXX:XXX:XXX
5.XXXX XXX XXX
How to achieve this.Please suggest me.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: `NSString *phoneRegex = @"^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{6,14}$";`

Comment: Hi Madan,I thought that Here you mentioned only one condition.But I want to implement all cases as I noted down in Question.

Answer (score 1):

Can be the Best way replace all the non-digit char

```
1.XXXXXXXXXX 2.XXXX-XXX-XXX 3.XXXX-XX-XX-XX 4.XXXX:XXX:XXX 5.XXXX XXX XXX
```

like

```
1.XXXXXXXXXX 2.XXXXXXXXXX 3.XXXXXXXXXX 4.XXXXXXXXXX 5.XXXXXXXXXX
```

and then reformat it. like

```
  1 (234) 567-8912
  1 (234) 567-8923 x4567
```

and On SO also there is [number of Question related this](https://www.google.co.in/#q=validate+phone+number+ios+using+regex&spell=1&sa=X&ei=rzGWUemiEsSNrQf43IGoBw&ved=0CCsQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.bmk&fp=26cfb212c432fa37&biw=1600&bih=756)

Answer (score 0):

I use this library for my phone number validations.

https://github.com/me2day/libPhoneNumber-iOS

Google wrote a great library and these guys ported it to Objective-C. More robust than I needed, it's good stuff